# hide bootstrap nav bar depending on width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap code:

```
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>                                                                          
  </ul>
```

Which collapses Link 1 and Link 2 into a collapsed menu when the screen width is small, otherwise it just shows in the nav bar. Is there a way to hide Link 1 and Link 2 in the nav bar when screen width is big, and only show them as collapsed menu options?

Comment: Hide entirely? Or you want to show "hamburger" icon on the big screen.

Comment: @makshh Hide both the links and hamburger icon entirely on big screen.

Comment: You can add `visible-xs` class to div with `nav` class.

Comment: that works. Thanks @makshh!